# How to prevent popstate event on page load (android browser)

Tags: javascript, events, android-browser, popstate

How to prevent firing `popstate` event on page load? **(This happens on Android Browser)**

Run the following snippet on Android Browser and see the result. *(Alternative link ro run the snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/heoceze0/1 )*

```js
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
  alert('popstate is called!!!');
};
```

```html
If you got no alert, that's ok...
```

Answer (score -2):

A `popstate` event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes between two history entries for the same document.

In order to prevent it from firing, simply use `event.preventDefault()`,

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('popstate is called!!!');
};
```